# In Unity play mode, how to change script private field and auto refresh

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

see my gif, in play mode, I change private field and refresh in unity editor, I'm sure script code is refresh but why game toolwin cannot be update? I know unity play mode can auto refresh, why this private field doesn't update
[image]

the console always raise:

```
The referenced script on this Behaviour is missing!
```

I don't know what does mean

Answer (score 5):

> The referenced script on this Behaviour is missing! I don't know what
>   does mean

It means that you're doing what you're not supposed to be doing.

**1**.Do not modify script during play move.

**2**.Do not refresh the project during play mode.

**3**.Avoid creating, deleting script during play mode or doing anything that requires re-compiling the script during play mode.

*These are ways to corrupt your project. Stop the game before doing any of these.*

If you want a private variable to show in the Editor so that you can change it in the Editor, use the `[SerializeField]` attribute:

```
[SerializeField]
private string field = "default";
```

Answer (score -1):

I doesn't find the way to make private field changed hot reload, but I can do following to instead:

for ex:

in play mode, change `string field = "pr";`[SerializeField] string field = "pr";`, it will be refresh and in unity editor inspector, this field can be set like public field

change field in inspector until find the satisfied value

manually put this satisfied to script